# populate hidden field from other text fields javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hidden, populate

I am trying to populate a hidden field by concatenating other textfields using javascript (without JQuery, just plain javascript).

The code I have below works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but dies in IE 8,9,10

---

**Javascript**

```
function buildhidden() {
var joinedvalues = textfield_id_1.value+textfield_id_2.value+textfield_id_3.value;
document.getElementById("hiddenfield_id").value = joinedvalues;
    };
```

**html input fileds**

```
<input type="text" name="textfield_id_1" id="textfield_id_1" value="" maxlength="1" onKeyUp="buildhidden();">
```

**hidden field**

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenfield_id" id="hiddenfield_id" value="" />
```

---

In IE, I get **"textfield_id_1 is not defined"** and no more.

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried explicitly declaring each text field:

```
var text1  = document.getElementById("hiddenfield_id").value;
var joinedvalues = text1+text2+ etc.
```

Which does not work either. I am a php dev, and JS is not my strong suite... any assistance is **very** welcome.

Comment: Can you provide some more code or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? This works as expected when I try it in IE8, so I think maybe your problem lies elsewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `document.getElementById('id here ')` as all browsers don't expose the ids of elements to the global scope.

```
id.value // bad practice, not cross-browser
document.getElementById('id').value // good, cross browser
```

So do this:

```
function buildhidden() {
    var joinedvalues = document.getElementById('textfield_id_1').value + document.getElementById('textfield_id_2').value + document.getElementById('textfield_id_3').value;
    document.getElementById("hiddenfield_id").value = joinedvalues;
}
```

Comment: Following this advice - using the above function works - was definitely the scope issue

Answer (score 0):

In IE colons of Id could get converted to underscore, you can use this method:

```
function convertNameToId(strId)
{
   reg = /:/g;
   return strId.replace(reg, "_");
}
```

and use:

```
document.getElementById(convertNameToId(strName))
```